# How to type a component prop to a higher order component when you don't have access to the HOC?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recharts, higher-order-components

I'm trying to pass some custom components to the `Tooltip`, `Legend`, `XAxis`, and `YAxis` components from the `recharts` library.

My issue is when I pass the component like

```
type Props = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  payload: { value: string };
  isGroupedByHour: boolean;
};

const CustomXAxisTick = ({ x, y, payload, isGroupedByHour }: Props) => {...}

<XAxis dataKey="time" tick={<CustomXAxisTick />} />
```

I get a type error on the `<XAxis .../>` line: `Type '{ }' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': x, y, payload`. Same for all the custom components.

I've tried passing the components inline like:

```
<Legend
                    align="center"
                    content={(props) => (
                      <div className="flex flex-shrink-0 items-center justify-center gap-4">
                        {props.payload?.map((p) => (
                          <span
                            key={p.id}
                            className={`text-xs flex items-center gap-1 `}
                          >
                            <span className="h-2 w-2 bg-current" />
                            {p.dataKey}
                          </span>
                        ))}
                      </div>
                    )}
                  />
```

It works, but I need to reuse the components, so I want them as separate components.

I've also tried directly using the custom components like this:

```
const CustomLegend = (
  <Legend
    align="center"
    content={(props) => (
      <div className="flex flex-shrink-0 items-center justify-center gap-4">
        {props.payload?.map((p) => (
          <span
            key={p.id}
            className={`text-xs text-[${p.color}] flex items-center gap-1 `}
          >
            <span className="h-2 w-2 bg-current" />
            {
              GRAPH_LABELS.decisions[
                p.dataKey as keyof typeof GRAPH_LABELS.decisions
              ]
            }
          </span>
        ))}
      </div>
    )}
  />
);


<BarChart
        data={new Array(100).fill(0).map((row, idx) => {
          return {
            time: idx,
            pass: Math.random() * 10000,
            fail: Math.random() * 10000,
            cant_decide: Math.random() * 1000,
          };
        })}
        margin={{
          top: 20,
          right: 30,
          left: 20,
          bottom: 5,
        }}
      >
        <CustomLegend />
</BarChart>
```

But `recharts` does not render this component at all.

My question is how do I properly type my custom components so that I don't get any type errors.

[Link to typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoUSWOAb3LjgCEUoAaB51gYQAtWYHRtwFIAzsBQA7AOJRgAEyFwAMkgDmSKUs7IxkKRIBuSbhCkwUwKUnacAKhAgAbGMDDKAGgEEAHsDFlAE0-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-b+BLevp4RvfIA9G6YNm9U-1G-6cDQU0WnAQnaRFaQgQZkXROBJmmOZFige5VmgjY4K2FAdmrQ44HrM41hg2w7nIEEwQheBoVhEBAIRGlkTRSCm2xMs0P2Yopgo6ken6UCGWZVk4HZTluWLHMBTgaURTFSVRNlQ0FSVFU1Q1LU3yEl9IPFKpLWtcU7QdcUXREo0YA9L0oB9P1oyDEN8AjKNMjjRNk3wNMMyzG9GFoKt9jrE4zjgFlLQtC1tzgCVFQ82ssKKR84H8q1uglOApitB9nwMpT9UfT9OG-Ajf2aIpHBcTowA4sDRgg9A3BMX5-kBe4wsOXUKksABpJAEMua51HuRh6sQJBwSgBQ+Q66x1CbEabiZe5wgAbQAXXuWVFmcC4rlGn9yAaPLVA0P0SqGMqUMYg4eOXE6Jq63VwV2H44Au7r7RyFBWvatabmm+aNqIwwSJhGBcDUTRtGosA6SmQG9rpRlhhZQT9QUYAjDgNBZVHAA5FAQAczAAV8KJcaqMReGuboqkC4BDRAMQqjQLRDSgOAACs-uATA21piw8PUFAwCqJ0XJzdy6RrMKtxrbIwBRStodhh99GkVy4G6NrxTAGtFHvJdkdRsQMax8UpQMqpfCGF8qhm0Ka2u6Bwjm-GjQeSnqY5+m4G53mzWCzXczSoT5e5FGUHRzGHN4KpUzgCdw7geZ1BpzkiAsANH19vV3JrJrnra72hMff20vnb2nwRowdWy77IVI-6QAK1x3GojIKsRxsGLxJQ4CWpBnGYuBa6K-aZZ41nUSbkw4AAMnH1vqwnqewprAEbhgXhGQgtkkA5LkeVLPkS+1oPdZDn0cYdk-fBplxHaQKnCcsGhmcuVm20uAQ3Z59TeOebQSUJvBY6qCcvAKZFAzHzPIbYI5mxNvpY0NRrB-HPhUKA3Q7r8AUBACcAslzDXyFIVOgt8yFjhlrHq5YUSd2cE2fArY2ydm7L2fsg5hyjnwOOJAU5ZzSXnIuEhsY3rqBrFAFAE4JR7k7O2OAABySRLZDy8CYceCUitGB3kVk+fOit3KoTbuLHmUswCDzXkuPiW9iEkJwdIfBS506ZxeuEQ4aswozTVrYtqc0c7mLzrgqxKiHo5g1B4-kj4S4F2mpwEx3JZjBi+uCH6cA5A8yPKMFEhjwkb34tvd8egDDGFMOYSw1g8ITkUMvFMAUACkAZeBIGAOoXgMAykWkqanPkLAoB8AEIrTO4pJxwG8FAIRjQUT+XpDWTAFkUQWlGRLKWOAJxNkUL4VJJDeLpK3kYrWbgsZTEWTwrW+RRxTHbDkXggjpDoJACkuAAAqaKAUAp7KXJgKwK04DHOXmc7QuArm3JihaR5pY0DSBgAAfQUP1RQ5w3knM+Rcn5dyHnKPwlrAJitshQHUNYcUGzcz-TAFMVM-ykXyDqTAKYABmIlKyASYDJXAQlAK9R-BgNXKYABWRl4RAm+TUSIWA4hJCyHkL2DqEBlaziJqwQZPpyVwHJcnKxfIqSPRairfAWykABjcD0cUfIq5wlCGxFBKdIgpzUaxESNJdX6vIoa4CcATUOsVbXNwYBkb5Lptav6uAXX10dWarWfIIbAxOLUqQPoXa2ADLEw0FgvVkWDb2f1iq2lItcTafABykhIpfj0AAkgoH0J4kUBA9KAHIwBzDeAwM3cUzznCFG5TmcZwZxRWVTOS7gZoACcAB2fATanVqNTSs9Nx8XnXhWbm7oBai2TpIaWqQ5a3BVprSYOtJxG1IpbSGWgVkABiFozTcDZfzQdAbsEjpIWO-AQKLBgoheC+dWtp2zvwMWlZi7l2VqkNWyqyZaD1q3SsndbbQzeG7d4bwTBuADsVhe3ObSOmwDSk+bJEJm5mAsFYGwUAvwbSAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for the CustomXAxisTick and the CustomYAxisTick, it simply works to adapt your code as follows:

```
    <XAxis dataKey="time" tick={(props)=> <CustomXAxisTick {...props}/>} />
    <YAxis tick={(props)=> <CustomYAxisTick {...props} />} />
```

In the other two cases, this does not work because the types you defined are not compatible with the recharts types.

> Property 'active' is optional in type '{ separator?: string | undefined; wrapperClassName?: string | undefined; labelClassName?: string | undefined; formatter?: Formatter<ValueType, NameType> | undefined; ... 24 more ...; useTranslate3d?: boolean | undefined; }' but required in type 'ToolTipProps'.

> Type '{ content?: ContentType | undefined; iconSize?: number | undefined; iconType?: IconType | undefined; layout?: LayoutType | undefined; align?: HorizontalAlignmentType | undefined; ... 476 more ...; key?: Key | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'LegendProps'.
> Types of property 'payload' are incompatible.
> Type 'Payload[] | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ id: string; color: string; dataKey: string; }[]'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ id: string; color: string; dataKey: string; }[]'.

In those two cases you must adapt your types to conform to the expectations from recharts.

I guess this thus only is half an answer, but I hope it is also half valuable, thus already sharing.

Comment: I fixed tooltip with `<Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip isGroupByHours={isGroupedByHour} />}/>` and giving the custom tooltip props the type `TooltipProps<number, string> & { isGroupByHours: boolean }`.  But even if I make payload optional in the custom legend, I'm getting the error that `dataKey` does not exist on the type. But obviously it's there, since I can see it being rendered and it's there in when I log the props

Comment: It is worth noting that the recharts types are sometimes plainly not correct / up to date with the content.

Comment: that is weird given that the types are coming from the same package itself

Comment: Agree, but the point is, development has been dormant for a while. We just started contributing and are now active again, uncovering issues such as this one.

Comment: If you make the payload optional in the LegendProps in the link from the playground, everything seems to work fine with the Legend code.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following solution.
Although I didn't test this code. But I was able to pass all of the checks in the playground. `I passed your custom props after copying the props from rechart.`

I also use the `as` operator to tell typescript to treat our values as the props we defined.

```js
<XAxis dataKey="time" tick={(props) => <CustomXAxisTick {...props} isGroupedByHour={true} />} />
 
<YAxis tick={(props) => <CustomYAxisTick {...props} />} />

<Tooltip content={(props) => <CustomTooltip {...props as ToolTipProps}/>} />

<Legend align="center" content={(props) => <CustomLegend {...props as unknown as LegendProps} />} />
```

Answer (score -1):

you can pass the component reference like this:

```
import {
  ...,
  TooltipProps,
  LegendProps,
} from "recharts";

const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }: TooltipProps<number, string>) ...

const CustomLegend = (props: LegendProps) => ( ...

  <XAxis dataKey="time" tick={CustomXAxisTick} />
  <YAxis tick={CustomYAxisTick} />
  <Tooltip content={CustomTooltip} />
  <Legend align="center" content={<CustomLegend />} />
```

Comment: it says that `DefaultLegendContent` is not exported from `recharts`

Comment: I was not able to check what version of recharts there is in the typescript playground, also there is no way to check what is exported so very hard to develop that way..

Comment: I'm using `recharts v2.3.2`

Comment: changed that answer with working code

Comment: I know it's a late reply, I just got around to trying this. By passing `tick={CustomXAxisTick}`, you're not even passing the custom prop I wanted to pass to the component.